# Adding a new table to a data source

Tags: c#

I am creating a database project in C#.NET 2010.

To use the database, I added a data source and gave it the path of my database. At that time, the database had only one table in it.

Now, I have added another table to the database, but it is not showing up in the data source. I have even tried refreshing it. What do I do so that the new table can show up in the data source?

Comment: What database are you using?  What have you tried, just refresh on the old datasource?

Comment: I am using MS Access 2010 database. I tried refreshing the database, but it didn't help. I found a method that works though. I add a new data source and it automatically detects the change.